# Why other blockchain would be better for monetary purposes than Ethereum?

Tags: storage, architecture

I have seen a comment multiple times that other blockchains would be better for storing value in monetary purposes than Ethereum. Why is that said? UTXO? Volatility?

The comment has been brought up related on long term investement and monetary discussions. I haven't found any technical reason for that, only ideological, that it's not the main purpose of Ethereum.

Comment: did you explore Multichain?

Comment: Hi there. I think this question will probably be closed as either being too broad or because any answers will be based on opinion. This board is better suited to technical questions with specific, objective answers. Perhaps Reddit might be a better place to ask this: reddit.com/r/ethereum

Comment: I understand. I added some clarification for the question, but I guess if the answer is based on opionion it means that there isn't any real architectural reason why Ethereum wouldn't be as good as any other secure blockchain.

Comment: Can you document your first sentence by linking to specific examples of the kind of 'comments' you are talking about?  You might also consider rewording your question to limit opinionated answers by asking: "Are there any technical or practical reasons why the Ethereum blockchain might not be considered as safe or useful for storing value?"

Comment: The purpose of the question was to get an argumentent answer to reply comments like mentioned here (of course the context and the tone of the text should be considered):  

https://medium.com/startup-grind/i-was-wrong-about-ethereum-804c9a906d36  

Now after more searching I think this Mr_Yucon_C's comment answers it well:  
  
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/5rj9w1/on_btc_eth_being_a_store_of_value/dd7s2u0/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by storing values. Bitcoin was built to be a currency. So the bitcoin block is built to store transactional values.

> The Bitcoin blockchain uses Merkle proofs in order to store the transactions in every block

Ethereum was built as a platform run by the ether currency. Ethereum stores more than just transactional values, it stores states, receipts, and transactions

> Every block header in Ethereum contains not just one Merkle tree, but three trees for three kinds of objects:
>   Transactions,
>   Receipts (essentially, pieces of data showing the effect of each transaction), and
>   State

It allows the Ethereum blockchain to more quickly look up account balances, smart contracts, etc without having to traverse down blocks and follow just the transactions.

You can read more in depth [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/11/15/merkling-in-ethereum/)